# Is it correct to write "teoremo X statas, ke" in the sense of "theorem X states that"?

Tags: word-usage

On several Vikipedio pages about physical laws or mathematical theorems,
I have found expressions like *[leĝo/teoremo X] statas, ke…* ([here](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C4%9Do_de_Hooke), [here](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoremo_de_Carmichael) and [here](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diver%C4%9Denca_teoremo)). To me, it looks like a crude Anglicism translating "theorem X states that". According to PIV, *stati* means "esti en ia difinita stato", which makes no sense when expressing the content of a theorem. But the large number of occurrences of that makes me doubt.

Is it indeed a misuse? If yes, what would be the correct verb? I would go for *asertas, ke*, which seems actually quite common.

Comment: I would question the placement of that comma - in any language

Comment: @Mawg If you are referring to *asertas, ke* — that comma is mandatory in Bulgarian, and I believe not only Bulgarian. Esperanto also requires it, as *ke* begins a subclause: [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html#i-mnc)

Comment: That comma is also mandatory in German. But not in French (and other Romance languages, I think). Zamenhof probably draw inspiration from German  / Slavonic languages on that question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, *statas ke* is definitely wrong. I agree with *asertas, ke*. Vikipedio should never be used as a reference of good Esperanto ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I agree that *statas ke* is wrong. *Asertas ke* is good.

Possible alternatives:

- diras
- indikas
- klarigas
- tekstas

Benson (CEED) has *aserti* and *diri*.

If you don't believe that theorems can speak, you can try something like *en la teoremo X oni diras ke...*

Comment: I once heard a theorem speak in a dream. ;-)